# Cassandra: CL != ALL on write will overload cluster

Tags: nosql, cassandra, replication, performance-testing

I am running a series of benchmarks with Cassandra. Among others, I tried the following configuration: 1 client node, 3 server nodes (same ring). All experiments are run after cleaning up the servers:

```
pkill -9 java; sleep 2; rm -r /var/lib/cassandra/*; ./apache-cassandra-1.2.2/bin/cassandra -f
```

then I run `cassandra-stress` from the client node (*3 replica*, consistency ANY/ALL):

```
[stop/clean/start servers]
./tools/bin/cassandra-stress -o INSERT -d server1,server2,server3 -l 3 -e ANY
[224 seconds]
[stop/clean/start servers]
./tools/bin/cassandra-stress -o INSERT -d server1,server2,server3 -l 3 -e ALL
[368 seconds]
```

One would deduce that decreasing the consistency level increases performance. However, there is no reason why this should happen. The bottleneck is the CPU on the servers and they all have to **eventually** do a **local write**. In fact, a careful read of the server logs reveals that hinted hand-off has taken place. Repeating the experiment, I sometimes get UnavailableException on the client and "MUTATION messages dropped" on the server.

Is this issue documented? Should CL != ALL be considered harmful on writes?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what your point is. Things appear to be working as designed.

Yes, if you're writing at CL.ONE it will complete the write faster that at CL.ALL - because it only has to get an ACK from one node - not all of them.

However, you're not measuring the time that will be taken to repair the data. You will get time spent queueing up and processing the hinted handoffs - however, nodes only hold this up for an hour.

Eventually, you'll have to run a `nodetool repair` to correct the consistency and delete the tombstones.

Comment: My point is (and I think your answer confirms it) that you do not actually improve performance by using CL.ONE instead of CL.ALL. Your client is unblocked quicker, but your servers may have to do additional processing as hinted handoffs or repairs. In this case, I am wondering why anybody would use CL.ONE?

Comment: Your point is correct - as to why use CL.ONE? It depends on whether you want Cass to respond to your online query faster. Generally, a Cass server isn't so heavily loaded that the processing time of a repair is a significant issue (although, in some cases, the repair time can be quite long).